# Python - missing module

Tags: python, module, plone, egg, plone-4.x

I am not familiar with Python and that's why I would like to ask this question.

I am trying to setup Plone CMS with windowsauthplugin on CentOS 7. I have already installed kerberos rpms for python (python-krbV) and ran buildout.
The plone daemon fails to load kerberos module. From the modules source:

```
...
else:
import kerberos
from kerberos import GSSError
```

The error I'm getting:

```
ImportError: No module named kerberos
```

When I try to import kerberos module in my *Hello world* python script on the same machine, no error occures. Is there a way to set an env variable to tell plone where to look for modules? Or what is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you by any chance have more than one Python installation? If you do, you need to make sure that the correct Python installation is being used. The packages aren't shared between different versions, meaning that it's possible you're using the incorrect one in your script, but the correct one in your helloworld.py example.

Comment: Instead of trying you hello world example with pure python, try to use the Plone python interpreter that is commonly in `parts/instance/bin/interpreter`.
If it can't import the module you are not using the right Python so you must investigate how you run the buildout.

Comment: You are right (and I was affraid of two different pythons), this interpreter does not know my "system" module. I'll try to find the way to add the kerberos module for this one or pointing to the system one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a Python interpreter that was built specifically for your Plone instance. Our installer does that automatically if it can't find a suitable Python for a given Plone version.

To fix it, add "kerberos" to the list of eggs contained in your buildout.cfg. Then rerun buildout.

Comment: Due to a bug in setuptools (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1121007) I had to download the .tar.gz of the egg manually to buildout-cache/downloads/dist